# I passed my German B2 exam. Thanks guys!

Tags: discussion

Few days ago I completed the last part I needed for getting my B2 certificate;schreiben. Now I am a certified intermediate German... doer?

Anyways, thanks guys for your passion and all the indepth explanation you gave me. As I had no teacher it was a bit hard but you guys helped fixed the lack for me.

Comment: Congratulations! Since I see no contained question here (despite the question mark) this would be better placed in a chat room, what you also did.